# Matlab insert image(.jpg) file to word file

Tags: matlab-figure

I want to insert the image to word file, If I try like the below code the word file show some unknown symbols like

```
"ΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰΰ"
```

My code:

```
figure,imshow(img1);

fid = fopen('mainfile.doc', 'a', 'n', 'UTF-8');
fwrite(fid, img1, 'char'); 
fclose(fid);
open('mainfile.doc');
```

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite` won't do this directly. You could try [Matlab report generator](http://www.mathworks.com/products/ML_reportgenerator/) if you have access to it or a file exchange submission, [OfficeDoc](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15192).